# Want heading as Delete in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hello all I have made one dynamic jqgrid,in that grid i have first column as checkbox,in that first column i want heading as "Delete"[image: snapshot]

please help me with that thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to replace the checkbox from the multiselect header to the text like "Delete" is the usage of `setLabel` method of jqGrid. You need just know that the name of multiselect column is `"cb"`. So the line of code

```
$("#list").jqGrid("setLabel", "cb", "Delete");
```

will do all what you want. I recommend you to use `multiselectWidth` option of jqGrid additionally. The option allows you to specify the width of the column. I used for example `multiselectWidth: 45` in [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetMultiselectLabel.htm). It displays the following results:

[image]

Comment: thanks oleg..but from where i can find the name of multiselect column   <tr class="ui-jqgrid-labels ui-sortable" role="rowheader">
<th id="ratePlanFearureGrid_rn" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader" style="width: 25px;">
<th id="ratePlanFearureGrid_cb" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader" style="width: 20px;">
<div id="jqgh_ratePlanFearureGrid_cb">
<input id="cb_ratePlanFearureGrid" class="cbox" type="checkbox" role="checkbox">
<span class="s-ico" style="display:none">
</div>
</th>

Comment: @user3381985: You are welcome! I don't understand your question. The column name is the `name` property in `colModel`. During initializing jqGrid it will be added the column with `name: "cb"`. The column `"rn"` is another example of such column. You can try to insert the following code `var cm = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"); alert(cm[0].name); alert(cm[1].name); alert(cm[2].name);` after the grid is created. You will see that columns `"rn"` and `"cb"` are exist before you main columns. You can use `setLabel` to modify the header of the columns.

Comment: @user3381985: For example `$("#list").jqGrid("setLabel", "rn", "<span style='color:red'>#</span>");` will set red text "#" as the header of the column holding row numbers (the column exist if you use `rownumbers: true` option).

Comment: ok... but the thing is that checkboxes are coming directly..this is my header array....var colHeaderArray=["Subscriber Phone Number (CTN)","Effective Date","Shared Data Group ID / Primary CTN","Voice Rate Plan Name","Billing Code","Price","Data Plan Name","Data Plan Billing Code","Price","Shared Data Group Plan","Current Data Plan Name","Current Billing Code","Current Price","Current Shared Data Group Plan","Feature 1 Action","Feature 1 Name"];.......i am not creating those checkboxes...

Comment: and this is my colModelArray..............var colModelArray=[{name:"CTN"},{name:"effectivedate"},{name:"sharedDataGIDPCTN",width:80},{name:"voiceRatePlanName"},{name:"voiceRateBillingCode"},{name:"voiceRatePrice"},{name:"dataPlanName"},{name:"dataPlanBillingCode"},{name:"dataPlanPrice"},{name:"sharedDataGroupPlan"},{name:"currentDataPlanName"},{name:"currentBillingCode"},{name:"currentPrice"},{name:"currentSharedDataGroupPlan"},{name:"feature1Action"},{name:"feature1Name"}];

Answer (score 0):

Try `colNames` like,

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
   colNames:'Delete,....',
   .....
});
```

Read [jqgrid-options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Comment: this checkbox is coming directly i dint hardcoded it....rest of the heading i hardcoded

Comment: `Checkboxes` are coming by default, so you have to change it by using `colNames option`.